# Unable to run mythril on a Hardhat project

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, solc, mythril

I have a hardhat project on my local system. For running Mythril security analysis I am using the following command:

myth analyze contracts/MyFile.sol --execution-timeout 900
Receiving the following error:

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".

How do I include openzeppelin and other file import locations in the command?

Mythril version v0.22.43

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/issues/1478#issuecomment-897462501), myth doesn't know what `@openzeppelin` is and you have to map this to explicit path to the imported contract.
You need to specify path to `node_modules` where `@openzeppelin` contracts is presented to help myth replace `@openzeppelin` string with original path and find them.

To do that you can create `.json` file with remappings (e.g. in project root) with such content:

```
{   
"remappings": [ "@openzeppelin/=/share/node_modules/@openzeppelin/" ]
}
```

*In my case absolut path starts with `/share/...` as I use docker volume.

Add this file path as option `--solc-json /path/to/remappings/file.json` to `analyze` command.

Final command using docker looks like:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/share  mythril/myth analyze  /share/Contract.sol --solc-json /share/remappings.json
```

(I runned docker container from project directory, but should works in your case too)

Final command without docker is almost the same:

```
myth analyze  /path/to/Contract.sol --solc-json /path/to/remappings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you create the path for if you were using remappings for:
"@rari-capital/solmate/src/utils/SafeCastLib.sol"

I can't seem to get my head around the framework you're using to create the remapping?

@bestpilot

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/74377)